# How to avoid size change when user drag window to top/right/left of screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I drag a window to the Top/Left/Right of screen, the window will be magnified or max automatically.

How to avoid system max or magnify this window when user drag it to specified area?

Comment: This is a global behaviour in Windows, don't try to change the behaviour in your app to fight against this. If your app doesn't work well maximised for whatever reason; fix that instead. Further, an application should never ever change system behaviour without users consent.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Make your application / Window resolution independent. What will happen if the user has a resolution of, say 8000 x 5000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable Snap, please follow [this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-turn-snap-on-or-off)

> To turn Snap on or off
>
> Open the Make the keyboard easier to use page by clicking the Start
>   button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking
>   Ease of Access, clicking Ease of Access Center, and then clicking Make
>   the keyboard easier to use.
>
> Under Explore all settings, click Make the mouse easier to use.
>
> Under Make it easier to manage windows, do one of the following:
>
> To turn Snap off, select the Prevent windows from being automatically
>   arranged when moved to the edge of the screen check box.
>
> To turn Snap on, clear the Prevent windows from being automatically
>   arranged when moved to the edge of the screen check box.
>
> Click OK.

As I mentioned in the comment, please don't try to manipulate this through (application specific) code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody...
I make a trick in SizeChanged event.
When size is changed, application will re-size to original size...